# Where do I find the necessary .jar file(s) to call the Mathematica engine from a java application?

Tags: free-wolfram-engine

I went to [www.github.com/WolframResearch](http://www.github.com/WolframResearch), but it wasn't clear where on that site the .jar file(s) could be found.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: If you have a copy of Mathematica (frontend + kernel)  installed on your system, they are likely to already be somewhere in your installation directory. If you're talking about the free developer kernel, the likely candidate is "WolframLanguageForJupyter", since Jupyter notebooks are a common front end for these configurations.